# Consultas pool.query Anidadas en Typescript y MySQL

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript, express, backend

Despues de de unas horas de revisar e intentar no queda otra que preguntar. Estoy desarrollando un backend en Node.Js Express.Js y Typescript. Lo tengo bastante organizado pero ahora intento listar todas las filas de una tabla Recetas(recipe_table) pero en un arregle que tambien contenga sus Ingredientes (mix_table). Lo pude hacer para una sola receta. Esto es lo mas cercano que he logrado estar.

```
public async read(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>{
    await pool.query('SELECT * FROM recipe_table', (err: any, recipes: any) => {
        if (!err) {
            let result: { recipe: any; mix: any; }[] = [];
            console.log(result);
            for (let recipe of recipes){
                pool.query('SELECT * FROM mix_table WHERE recipe_id = ?', [recipe.recipe_id], (err: any, mix: any) => {
                    result.push({ recipe, mix });
                });
            }
            res.status(200).json({ result });
        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ err, message: "Ha ocurrido un error en su peticion" });
        }
    });
}
```

Saludos a todos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: El problema que realmente pasa es que los valores que le agrego a result mediante push una vez que sale de pool.query no los saca de ahí... Llevo varios días y aún no encuentro la forma de verdad me vendría bien una ayuda.. Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para conectarte a MySQL? Será [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) o [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2)? ¿Podrías aclarar eso para darte una respuesta? Saludos

Comment: uso mysql... Gracias

Comment: Cual seria la diferencia si se usa mysql y mysql2?? Si laguien me pudiera dar una ayuda le estaria agradecido....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema está en el manejo de los procesos asíncronos.

Tienes un bucle tipo `for` y por cada iteración haces un llamado al método `query()`. El mismo recibe una función `callback` la cual es la que recibirá el resultado de la consulta. Pero el bucle `for` no esperará ese resultado, al contrario seguirá iterando sobre los elementos hasta finalizar. Es por ello que al enviar el resultado al cliente el `Array` de resultados aún no ha sido llenado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución a este problema es usar [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all), que devolverá una Promesa que se resuelve satisfactoriamente cuando cada promesa del iterable se resuelve también satisfactoriamente.

Por ejemplo:

```js
public async read(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void>{
  await pool.query('SELECT * FROM recipe_table', (err: any, recipes: any) => {
    // si hay algún error devolvemos el mensaje al cliente
    if(err) {
      return res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Oooops there was a error',
        error: err.message
      });
    }
    // con el resultado de nuestra consulta a BD creamos un iterable de promesas
    // para ello usamos el método map() del tipo Array que devuelve
    // un valor por cada elemento procesado
    // el valor devuelto en cada elemento del iterable será una Promesa.
    let promises: any[] = recipes.map(recipe => {
      // devolvemos una Promesa
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        pool.query(
        'SELECT * FROM mix_table WHERE recipe_id = ?', 
        [recipe.recipe_id], 
        (err: any, mix: any) => {
          // si se produce un error, rechazamos la Promesa
          if(err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          // Si no hay errores, resolvemos la Promesa pasando como argumento
          // el objeto que deseamos sea almacenado en el iterable
          resolve({recipe, mix});
        }); // fin pool.query
      }); // fin new Promise
    }); // fin recipes.map

    // Ahora podemos usar el método Promise.all(<iterable>) y le pasamos
    // nuestro array de promesas como argumento
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(result: any [] => {
      // si todas las promesas se resolvieron correctamente, result será un Array
      // con los valores de cada item de recipes procesados
      res.status(200).json({
        result
      });
    })
    .catch(err: any => {
      // si alguna promesa es rechazada, aqui capturamos el error y se devuelve
      // el mensaje apropiado al cliente
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Oooops there was a error',
        error: err.message
      });
    });
  }); // fin await pool.query
}// fin async
```

Como puedes observar, la idea es obtener el `Array` de resultados cuando todas las Promesas (representadas por las consultas a DB por cada elemento de `recipes`) sean resueltas.

De esta forma siempre estarás devolviendo un resultado al usuario, sin importar la cantidad de elementos a los que deba hacer consulta.

Sin embargo, pienso que hacerlo de esta forma no es tan eficiente como el realizar una petición única usando alguna consulta SQL estructurada. Habría que revisar cómo tienes organizados los datos y sus relaciones para intentar construir una consulta SQL que te traiga el resultado tal como lo deseas.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente consulta podría traer una lista con los nombres de las recetas y los nombres de los ingredientes:

```
SELECT recipe_table.name AS 'Recipe', mix_table.name as 'Ingredient' FROM recipe_table JOIN mix_table ON recipe_table.id = mix_table.recipe_id
```

Lo cual puede producir un resultado parecido al siguiente:

```sh
Recipe                                             Ingredient                                        
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
Crema Catalana                                     Azúcar                                            
Crema Catalana                                     Leche                                             
Paella Valenciana                                  Arroz                                             
Paella Valenciana                                  Gambas
```

Dependiendo de los resultados que obtengas podrías luego filtrar los mismos para hacer una lista con elementos del tipo `{ recipe_name: <string>, recipe_ingredients: [ ... ] }`.

Lo que sucede es que realizo una sola consulta a DB y luego sólo filtro los resultados. Eso siempre es más eficiente que realizar varias consultas a la DB.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

**Nota**

La diferencia entre el módulo [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) y el módulo [`mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) es simplemente que el segundo es una mejora sobre el primero, de hecho mucho de su código es totalmente compatible, pero en `mysql` se agregan ciertas características no presentes en `mysql`:

(Tomado de la documentación)

1. Desempeño mejorado y más rápido
2. [Sentencias preparadas](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Prepared-Statements.md)
3. Protocolo de Logging Binario de MySQL
4. Soporte para [MySQL Server API](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/MySQL-Server.md)
5. Soporte extendido para *Encoding* y *Collation*
6. [Envoltorio de Promesas](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md) (lo que te permite usar `async / await` o `then / catch`)
7. Compresión
8. Soporte SSL y [*Switch* de Autenticación](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/tree/master/documentation/Authentication-Switch.md)
9. [*Streams* perzonalizados](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Extras.md)
10. [Pooling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-connection-pools)